# Windows Server 2003 R2 and Exchange

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange-2003

I plan on learning and installing:
1)AD for AD authentication with UNIX systems
2)Exchange for my intranet email

I have the windows server 2003 R2 Standard edition software.
I intend to have about 20 UNIX clients connect using AD authentication via software such as likewise open/sssd etc. I also need to setup intranet email.

Am I good for the AD part and what MS exchange software do I need to purchase which would not be incompatible with my windows server 2003 R2 standard edition. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Should have asked this in the same post. Do I need two seperate systems to host windows server 2003 and exchange or will just one system suffice. What kind of cpu and RAM requirements are we looking at. This is just for learning and testing

Comment: Please edit your post to include additional content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, and only if this is just for a playbox / test setup, you can combine the 2003 Domain Controller Role along with Exchange Server in a single instance. Exchange Server 2003 ([32-bit only](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/924046)) and 2007 ([64-bit only](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998874.aspx)) were/are supported on the Server 2003 platform.

Re memory requirements for Exchange 2007: as you are going to use what is referred to as a "Multi-Role configuration", the [recommended system's memory configuration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738124(v=exchg.80).aspx) is

> *8 GB plus from 2 MB to 5 MB per mailbox*

Note that Server 2003 R2 [extended support has ended in July 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/windows-server-2003/), thus ***you will not get security fixes for any newer security-related issues***. Make sure your system has sufficient isolation from any productive environment as it would make for a veritable attack vector.